# Google ecommerce analytics not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

First of all, I am a beginner to analytics and JavaScript.

I am trying to add Google analytics for my e-commerce shopping website implemented in Opencart.

The idea is to get details of most viewed products, products added to cart, most ordered product, top category, demographics etc.

In the first step to test e-commerce analytics, I copied the tracking code snippet to `Extentions > Analytics > Google analytis (Installed) > 'Google analytics code'` in Opencart console.

snippet:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-y', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '1000',
    'affiliation': 'something',
    'revenue': '200',
    'shipping': '10',
    'tax': '33.32'
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '1000',
    'name': 'red-shoes',
    'sku': 'RS-M',
    'category': 'Mens Shoes',
    'price': '100',
    'quantity': '2'
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I have enabled E-commerce in `Admin > E-commerce settings > 'Enable e-commerce'` in Google analytics console.

But no e-commerce data is been displayed in google analytics reporting console. Only the informations like, Real-time overview, Active users now, locations, Top active pages are showing in the reporting page.

[image: E-commerce report overview]

Is there any settings that i missed? or did i do it wrong?

Comment: How long did you wait it can take 24 -48 hours for data to show up in the standard reports. If real-time shows data then it "should be working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is from classic GA E-commerce but report you're checking is from enhanced e-commerce (they're slightly different, enhanced e-commerce has more reports and data). Implement full enhanced e-commerce on site (docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) or disable "Enhanced E-commerce Reporting" in admin panel and leave code you already have.

You can also check here great demo how to implement enhanced e-commerce: https://enhancedecommerce.appspot.com

Comment: Do we have to add `ga("ec:addProduct",other_parameters);`  code for every single product in our website? I have added the code above in a single page; But in your link to demo page, there is `addProduct` code added to every single products.

Comment: No. Use `ec:addProduct` only once for e.g: to measure product click on list (`ec:addProduct` + `ec:setAction` + typical ga event to send data), adding to cart single product, removing from cart (single product). If you want for e.g: remove many products from cart then you need to make `ec:addProduct` for each product which you want to remove.  But for each product shown on single page you should use: `ec:addImpression` to measure all products impression.

Comment: So, I would be using `addImpression` as i need details of every product in my website. And may I know how can I get other details of the products? (Like price, category, specification, etc.)